# Where does mutt save email while you're writing it?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mutt

I was in the middle of writing an email when my computer shut down. I had already `:w` saved it, but not `:wq` saved-to-drafts.

Where should I look for the partial email? This is on Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutt's message drafts reside in the temporary directory (`\tmp`), and are named as `mutt-<hostname>-<unique-id>`.

Note that many systems clean up the temp directory on system startup.

Comment: It's /tmp, not \tmp.  This isn't Windows, THIS. IS. LINUX!  ;-)

Comment: Debian has changed the default to /var/tmp in August 2020.  Ubuntu, being a Debian derivative, "does" the same (just checked, and it seems to be the Debian package).

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the default config, your messages are probably in `/tmp` (assuming that you haven't rebooted or otherwise cleaned up `/tmp`), but strictly speaking Mutt uses the following locations in order:

1. the directory specified by the `tmpdir` variable in your `~/.muttrc`
2. if that's not set, the directory specified by the `$TMPDIR` environment variable
3. if that's also not set, the `/tmp` directory

You may wish to set a `tmpdir` value in your `~/.muttrc` precisely to help you recover emails you were writing at the time of a computer crash. Eg:

```
set tmpdir = ~/.mutt-tmp
```

Source: [Mutt manual: tmpdir variable](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#tmpdir)

Comment: Very helpful answer - thanks.  Unfortunately, it also uses tmpdir as a staging area when saving your whole inbox. Since I tend to have a very large inbox, I want to set /tmp to a place that is automatically cleared out periodically, but I want drafts to be preserved. Perhaps mutt needs a way to set these two independently....